# MySql query comparing DATE column to specific date doesnt return specific results to date intead returns all entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have the following query on a mysql table

```
   select * from scheduled_work where id_location = {$location} and scheduled_date = '{$date}' and is_active
```

scheduled_date is a column type date (2016-07-27)

When i run the query i dont only get results for a specific date instead i get results for all entries in the table

heres the table structure

```
#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
1   id_scheduled_work   int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  Change Change   Drop Drop   

More

2   id_schedule_hours   int(11)         No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

More

3   id_truck    int(11)         No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

More

4   id_driver   int(11)         No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

More

5   scheduled_date  date            No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

More

6   id_location int(11)         No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

More

7   id_user int(11)         No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

More

8   created_at  timestamp           No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP       Change Change   Drop Drop   

More

9   updated_at  timestamp       on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP No  0000-00-00 00:00:00 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP Change Change   Drop Drop   

More

10  is_active   tinyint(1)          No  1
```

and heres sample entries

```
     Full texts     id_scheduled_work   id_schedule_hours   id_truck    id_driver   scheduled_date  id_location     id_user     created_at  updated_at  is_active
Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   1   1   1   1   2016-07-22  1   1   2016-07-22 17:44:40     0000-00-00 00:00:00     1
Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   2   2   1   1   2016-07-22  1   1   2016-07-22 18:02:20     0000-00-00 00:00:00     1
Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   3   1   1   1   2016-07-27  1   1   2016-07-28 01:49:53     2016-07-28 01:52:08     1
Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   4   1   3   1   2016-07-27  1   1   2016-07-28 01:49:53     2016-07-28 01:52:19     1
```

Comment: i think you can use 'like' instead of '=' for date field.

Comment: Did echo  $date prints the proper date?

Comment: i have tried    select * from scheduled_work where id_location = {$location} and scheduled_date like '2016-07-27' and is_active but get teh same results

Comment: Try it by removing of is_active  select * from scheduled_work where id_location = '$location' and scheduled_date = '$date'

Comment: I have also done that it just returns the same results for some reason

Comment: Don't you need to set is_active to a value?

Comment: no it recognizes is_active as boolean and that is read as true

Comment: If you are getting all the results in the table, it means that none of the filters are working. Can you post the table definition and some records?

Comment: This is unreadable.